# The Number of conjugate classes of a non-abelian group of order $729$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, p-groups

Howti identify  Number of conjugate classes of a non-abelian group of order $729$.

A group of order $p^3$ where $p$ is prime have  $p^2+p-1$ number of conjugacy class.But my question is what is the general rule of $p^n$ where $p$ is prime. if any such rule exists?

Comment: The number is $k(G)=p^{n-1}+p-1$ for a non-abelian group $G$ of order $p^n$ with $|G'|=p=|Z(G)|$, see the duplicate. Otherwise we have upper and lower bounds.

Comment: For a proof see [here](https://math.wvu.edu/~capantea/pdf/conjugacy.pdf).